# firebase.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property

Tags: javascript, firebase

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'kategoriler.Nature.thumbnail'

Where do you think the problem is when I get the following error? I did it by watching a new video, but I didn't work either. I also created the database through the firebase and I did the permissions true. Please help me. Thank you very much in advance.

Error Console

[image]

```
$("#save-category").click(function(){
            $("#category-name").removeClass("is-invalid");
            $("#category-desc").removeClass("is-invalid");
            $("#category-thumbnail").removeClass("is-invalid");
            var catname = $("#category-name").val();
            var desc = $("#category-desc").val();
            var thumbnail = $("#category-thumbnail").prop("files")[0];

            if(!catname){
                $("#category-name").addClass("is-invalid");
                return;
            }
            if(!desc){
                $("#category-desc").addClass("is-invalid");
                return;
            }
            if(thumbnail == null){
                $("#category-thumbnail").addClass("is-invalid");
                return;
            }
            if($.inArray(thumbnail["type"], validImageTypes)<0){
                $("#category-thumbnail").addClass("is-invalid");
                return;
            }
            var database = firebase.database().ref("kategoriler/"+catname);
            database.once("value").then(function(snapshot){
                if(snapshot.exists()){
                    $("#result").attr("class", "alert alert-danger");
                    $("#result").html("Bu kategori zaten var");
                } else {
                    var name = thumbnail["name"];
                    var ext = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf("."), name.length);
                    var thumbname = new Date().getTime();
                    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(catname + "/" + thumbname + ext);
                    var uploadTask = storageRef.put(thumbnail);

                    uploadTask.on("state_changed",
                        function progress(snapshot){
                            var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
                            $("#upload-progress").html("%" + percentage);
                            $("#upload-progress").attr("style", "width:"+percentage + "%");
                        },

                        function error(err){

                        },

                        function complete(){
                            var thumbnailUrl = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
                            var cat = {
                                "thumbnail": thumbnailUrl,
                                "desc": desc
                            };
                            database.set(cat, function(err){
                                if(err){
                                    $("#result").attr("class", "alert alert-danger");
                                    $("#result").html(err.message);
                                } else {
                                    $("#result").attr("class", "alert alert-success");
                                    $("#result").html("Kategori eklendi");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    );
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is in "function complete" the url cannot be undefined

Have a look at how they are doing it in the Firebase doc:

```
  function() {
  // Handle successful uploads on complete
  // For instance, get the download URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...
  uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
    console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
  });
```

Here is the link of the page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files

Answer (score 0):

In your function complete() use storageRef directly to get Download URL storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url)   will give the downloadURL in argument url.

```
function complete(){
                    storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url){
                    console.log(url);

                    var cat={
                        "thumbnail":url,
                        "desc":desc
                    };

                    database.set(cat,function(err){
                            if(err){
                                $("#result").attr("class","alert alert-danger");
                                $("#result").html("Category already exist");
                            }
                            else{
                                $("#result").attr("class","alert alert-success");
                                $("#result").html("Category added");
                            }
                        });
                });                        

                }
```